# Adding quotes to a string in a file

Tags: mysql, sed

I currently have an SQL file filled with insert statements in the form:

```
 INSERT INTO
 database.table(primary_key,
 foreign_key, url_one,
 url_two, int_one,
 int_two, int_three) VALUES
 (266,7,https://some.url.com/image_one.png,https://some.url.com/image_two.png,266,1440,900);
```

I've now realised that the URL strings will need quotation marks around them before I can execute them in MySQL. What command can I use to place quotation marks around the URL string?

I tried to use 'sed' to do it but I couldn't get the command right as I don't completely know the syntax of what I want to achieve:

```
sed -e "s/(https://).*(\.png)/\"(https://)$1(.png)\"/g" some_sql_file.sql
```

Running this results in:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 12:
```

> unknown option to `s'

Any help would be much appreciated as I want to avoid regenerating the SQL file just to put in the quotation marks if at all possible.

Comment: Remember. Manpages are your friend! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
sed -e 's@\(https\?://[^,]*\),@"\1",@g' FILE
```

This looks for a expression starting with `http` and an optional `s` followed by `://`. Then it takes everything up to the first `,`. This expression will be enclosed by `"`.

Comment: Thanks for that! How would I get it to write the changes back into the file?

Comment: @Rosco: Use the `-i` option to `sed`.